# Execute command on specific screen on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, gnu-screen

I use screen on CentOS to run my script. Example:

Output command screen -ls:

```
There is a screen on:
        session-1      (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-root
```

And I Run:

```
screen -r -S "session-1" -d -m -p 0 /tmp/script1.sh
screen -r -S "session-1" -d -m -p 1 /tmp/script2.sh
screen -r -S "session-1" -d -m -p 2 /tmp/script3.sh
```

but it's not work. I want script1.sh run on screen:0, script1.sh run on screen:1, script1.sh run on screen:2,... with option `-p <screen number>`. But it's not work. Please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Have windows `1` and `2` already been created within screen `session-1`?

Comment: yes, i have 10 window in session-1 and i want to run 10 script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have 10 window in session-1 and i want to run 10 script.

Since `session-1` and its windows have already been created, we don't need options `-d -m`. Also, of options `-r -S` we need only one. To execute a program in an already existing session we need option `-X exec …`. So, the resulting commands would be like:

```
screen -r session-1 -p 0 -X exec /tmp/script1.sh
```

But when I tried this with `screen` versions 4.0, the program was executed in the current (last used) window, not in the window specified by `-p`. Apparently `-p` doesn't work with `-X`. What did work was:

```
screen -r session-1 -p 0 -X stuff /tmp/script1.sh$'\n'
screen -r session-1 -p 1 -X stuff /tmp/script2.sh$'\n'
screen -r session-1 -p 2 -X stuff /tmp/script3.sh$'\n'
```